# Remove files with names matching a pattern in a directory and preserve the rest

Tags: linux, files, directory, delete

I have a folder with files named `MA1`, `MA2`, .... `MA-i` (without extension and in total more than 110000)  with other file and other subdirectory.

I wish to delete all `MA-i` file and preserve the other files and the subdirectory

I tried without success

```
a@LinuxA:~/CLionProjects/ETC1/cmake-build-debug$ rm -f MA*
```

Comment: @slm they are more than 110000 files. Maybe is it a time issue?

Comment: try this - `find . -name "MA-*" -rm -f "{}" +`

Comment: @slm  yes, I have 1100000 file named MA1, MA2,..., MA1100000  with other file (e.g. T1, T2,...T100). I wish to delete only the MAx files. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ah, OK so do this - `find . -name "MA*" -rm -f "{}" +`

Comment: My sentiment as well. We're not getting the full picture here IMO.

Comment: @don_crissti I got a error message

Comment: @slm I got a error message

Comment: The error says it can not find the comand "find"

Comment: @don_crissti

I wrote: 
alessandro@LinuxAle:~/CLionProjects/ETCS/cmake-build-debug$ - find . -name "MA*" -rm -f "{}" +

and the error was
-: comando non trovato (in english comand not found)

Comment: What operating system shell and environment are you using?

Comment: I have ubuntu on virtualmachine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -iname 'MA*' | while read L ; do echo rm "$L"; rm "$L"; done
```

For progress, if your storage volume is dying you may not be able to delete certain files the normal way and you'll see it stop and hang on a particular file at which point you can use timeout to skip the ones that don't work.

Comment: I wrote alessandro@LinuxAle:~/CLionProjects/ETCS/cmake-build-debug$ find . -iname 'MA*' | while read L ; echo rm "$L"; rm "$L"; done

and I got this Error message

bash: errore di sintassi vicino al token non atteso "done" (in English syntax error close to token )